# bug? bash select-- typed data is returned as "unbound variable"

Tags: bash, select

I'm running Linux 3.10.0-693.2.2.el7.x86_64, and for the life of me can't figure why this would happen.  It appears to be a bug and shellchecker finds no issues.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -o nounset

### functions
options=(one two three)

select var in "${options[@]}"; do
    # make sure it is a valid choice
    if (( REPLY <= ${#options[@]} )) && [[ $REPLY  =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; then
        case $var in
            one)   exit;;
            two)  df -h /tmp;;
            *)      echo $var;;
        esac
        break
    else
        printf "Invalid selection.\n" >&2
    fi
```

I used set -xv to trouble shoot, but here's the output without it.  In production, the options[@] will be set by a command, and the number they return will be dynamic.  So I want the menu to execute a command in *) on $var-- but I have to check for an out of bounds selection in REPLY.  Here is the output.

```
$ bad_select.bash
1) one
2) two
3) three
#? 4
Invalid selection.
#? t
/home/lc5550358/bin/select_menu.wip: line 9: t: unbound variable
```

The `t` that I typed?  I can also avoid the unbound variable, but entering `k=2` or `var` (the latter is defined in the select).  Why and what is the work around
(`set -o nounset` is needed)?

Comment: try: `if [[ $REPLY  =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] && (( $REPLY <= ${#options[@]} )); then`

Comment: Doesn't `select` itself already make sure that the choice is valid? Or is the point that you want to print an error message if it is invalid?

Comment: `REPLY` isn't set if you make an invalid selection, and the arithmetic statement is informing you of that.

Comment: Thanks all-- I've used jm666's answer.  Benjamin, select doe not, the case statement needs to, but I have need of *).  chepner, shortly after I posted this (after a few hours of debugging the whole script), I realized that REPLY is unset (like it was `declare -i`).  I find the error message vague, but par for the course.  Thanks everyone for helping me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inside an arithmetic expression, bash evaluates the *value* of a variable.  Thus, in `(( REPLY <= ${#options[@]} ))`, the value of `REPLY` is evaluated.  If the value of `REPLY` is `t` and `t` is unbound, then that triggers the unbound variable error.

Observe:

```
$ t=2*3; REPLY=t; echo $(( REPLY + 2 ))
8
$ REPLY=t; t=a+b; a=6; b=c; c=10; echo $(( REPLY + 2 ))
18
$ unset t; REPLY=t; echo $(( REPLY + 2 ))
bash: t: unbound variable
```

As [jm666](https://stackoverflow.com/users/632407/jm666) explained, one solution is reverse the order of the tests so that arithmetic is done on REPLY only after it is verified that REPLY is an integer.

Alternatively, you can test `var` instead of `REPLY`:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -o nounset

### functions
options=(one two three)

select var in "${options[@]}"; do
    # make sure it is a valid choice
    if [ "$var" ]; then
        case "$var" in
            one)   exit;;
            two)  df -h /tmp;;
            *)      echo "$var";;
        esac
        break
    else
        printf "Invalid selection.\n" >&2
    fi
done
```

This works because `var` is only assigned a value if the user provided a valid response at the prompt.  Otherwise, `var` is set to be null.

#### Documentation

From the `man bash` section on arithmetic evaluation:

> Shell variables are allowed as operands; parameter expansion is
>   performed before the expression is evaluated.  Within an expression,
>   shell variables may also be referenced by    name without using the
>   parameter expansion syntax.  A shell variable that is null or unset
>   evaluates to 0 when referenced by name without using the parameter 
>   expansion  syn‐    tax.   **The  value of a variable is evaluated as an
>   arithmetic expression when it is referenced**, or when a variable which
>   has been given the integer attribute using declare -i    is assigned a
>   value.  A null value evaluates to 0.  A shell variable need not have
>   its integer attribute turned on to be used in an expression.

Comment: awesome info.  Thanks.